# Access 64 bit DLL from 32 bit DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, c++builder, c++builder-5

I'm porting the [CEF4Delfi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) library to Borland C++Builder 5. I make a BPL package from the ported CEF4Delfi source and reference it from my C++Builder 5 code.

I work on Windows 10 64bit.

While porting, I'm stuck on importing DLL functions.

Here is part of the imports:

```pascal
const
  Kernel32DLL = 'kernel32.dll';
  SHLWAPIDLL  = 'shlwapi.dll';
  NTDLL       = 'ntdll.dll';
  User32DLL   = 'User32.dll';

function ProcessUnderWow64(hProcess: THandle; Wow64Process: PBOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external Kernel32DLL name 'IsWow64Process';
function PathIsRelativeAnsi(pszPath: LPCSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathIsRelativeA';
function PathIsRelativeUnicode(pszPath: LPCWSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathIsRelativeW';
function GetGlobalMemoryStatusEx(lpBuffer: LPMEMORYSTATUSEX): BOOL; stdcall; external Kernel32DLL name 'GlobalMemoryStatusEx';
function PathCanonicalizeAnsi(pszBuf: LPSTR; pszPath: LPCSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathCanonicalizeA';
function PathCanonicalizeUnicode(pszBuf: LPWSTR; pszPath: LPCWSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathCanonicalizeW';
function PathIsUNCAnsi(pszPath: LPCSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathIsUNCA';
function PathIsUNCUnicode(pszPath: LPCWSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathIsUNCW';
function PathIsURLAnsi(pszPath: LPCSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathIsURLA';
function PathIsURLUnicode(pszPath: LPCWSTR): BOOL; stdcall; external SHLWAPIDLL name 'PathIsURLW';
function ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hWnd: HWND; Reason: LPCWSTR): Bool; stdcall; external User32DLL;
function ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(hWnd: HWND): Bool; stdcall; external User32DLL;
```

Due the linking, I get errors such as:

```
Error: Unresolved external 'PathIsRelativeA' referenced from C:\REPOS\CEF4DELPHI\SOURCE\UCEFMISCFUNCTIONS.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'AlphaBlend' referenced from C:\REPOS\CEF4DELPHI\SOURCE\UCEFBUFFERPANEL.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'IsWow64Process' referenced from C:\REPOS\CEF4DELPHI\SOURCE\UCEFMISCFUNCTIONS.OBJ
```

Here is the temporary `MAKE0000.@@@` linking file from C++Builder:

```
 -D"" -aa -Tpp -x -Gn -Gl -Gi -v -L..\source;..\packages;..\packages\res;..\addons;..\winlib;c:\windows\system32;L:\Lib;T:\bin\..\lib\obj;T:\bin\..\lib; +
 c0pkg32.obj vcl50.bpi Memmgr.Lib sysinit.obj ..\addons\MaxiSysUtils.obj   ..\source\uCEFAccessibilityHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFApp.obj   ..\source\uCEFApplication.obj   ..\source\uCEFApplicationCore.obj   ..\source\uCEFAudioHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFAuthCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFBaseRefCounted.obj   ..\source\uCEFBaseScopedWrapper.obj   ..\source\uCEFBeforeDownloadCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFBinaryValue.obj   ..\source\uCEFBitmapBitBuffer.obj   ..\source\uCEFBoxLayout.obj   ..\source\uCEFBrowser.obj   ..\source\uCEFBrowserProcessHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFBrowserView.obj   ..\source\uCEFBrowserViewComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFBrowserViewDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFBufferPanel.obj   ..\source\uCEFButton.obj   ..\source\uCEFButtonComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFButtonDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFChromium.obj   ..\source\uCEFChromiumCore.obj   ..\source\uCEFChromiumEvents.obj   ..\source\uCEFChromiumFontOptions.obj   ..\source\uCEFChromiumOptions.obj   ..\source\uCEFChromiumWindow.obj   ..\source\uCEFClient.obj   ..\source\uCEFCommandLine.obj   ..\source\uCEFCompletionCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFConstants.obj   ..\source\uCEFContextMenuHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFContextMenuParams.obj   ..\source\uCEFCookieAccessFilter.obj   ..\source\uCEFCookieManager.obj   ..\source\uCEFCookieVisitor.obj   ..\source\uCEFCustomStreamReader.obj   ..\source\uCEFDeleteCookiesCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFDevToolsMessageObserver.obj   ..\source\uCEFDialogHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFDictionaryValue.obj   ..\source\uCEFDisplay.obj   ..\source\uCEFDisplayHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFDomDocument.obj   ..\source\uCEFDomNode.obj   ..\source\uCEFDomVisitor.obj   ..\source\uCEFDownLoadItem.obj   ..\source\uCEFDownloadHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFDownloadImageCallBack.obj   ..\source\uCEFDownloadItemCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFDragAndDropMgr.obj   ..\source\uCEFDragData.obj   ..\source\uCEFDragHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFEndTracingCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFExtension.obj   ..\source\uCEFExtensionHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFFileDialogCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFFillLayout.obj   ..\source\uCEFFindHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFFocusHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFFrame.obj   ..\source\uCEFFrameHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFGetExtensionResourceCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFImage.obj   ..\source\uCEFInterfaces.obj   ..\source\uCEFJsDialogCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFJsDialogHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFJson.obj   ..\source\uCEFKeyboardHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFLabelButton.obj   ..\source\uCEFLabelButtonComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFLayout.obj   ..\source\uCEFLibFunctions.obj   ..\source\uCEFLifeSpanHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFLinkedWinControlBase.obj   ..\source\uCEFLinkedWindowParent.obj   ..\source\uCEFListValue.obj   ..\source\uCEFLoadHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFMediaObserver.obj   ..\source\uCEFMediaRoute.obj   ..\source\uCEFMediaRouteCreateCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFMediaRouter.obj   ..\source\uCEFMediaSink.obj   ..\source\uCEFMediaSinkDeviceInfoCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFMediaSource.obj   ..\source\uCEFMenuButton.obj   ..\source\uCEFMenuButtonComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFMenuButtonDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFMenuButtonPressedLock.obj   ..\source\uCEFMenuModel.obj   ..\source\uCEFMenuModelDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFMiscFunctions.obj   ..\source\uCEFNavigationEntry.obj   ..\source\uCEFNavigationEntryVisitor.obj   ..\source\uCEFOAuth2Helper.obj   ..\source\uCEFOLEDragAndDrop.obj   ..\source\uCEFOSRIMEHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFOverlayController.obj   ..\source\uCEFPDFPrintCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFPDFPrintOptions.obj   ..\source\uCEFPanel.obj   ..\source\uCEFPanelComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFPanelDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFPostData.obj   ..\source\uCEFPostDataElement.obj   ..\source\uCEFPrintDialogCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFPrintHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFPrintJobCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFPrintSettings.obj   ..\source\uCEFProcessMessage.obj   ..\source\uCEFRegistration.obj   ..\source\uCEFRenderHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFRenderProcessHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFRequest.obj   ..\source\uCEFRequestContext.obj   ..\source\uCEFRequestContextHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFRequestHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFResolveCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFResourceBundle.obj   ..\source\uCEFResourceBundleHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFResourceHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFResourceReadCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFResourceRequestHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFResourceSkipCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFResponse.obj   ..\source\uCEFResponseFilter.obj   ..\source\uCEFRunContextMenuCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFRunFileDialogCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFSSLStatus.obj   ..\source\uCEFSchemeHandlerFactory.obj   ..\source\uCEFSchemeRegistrar.obj   ..\source\uCEFScrollView.obj   ..\source\uCEFScrollViewComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFSelectClientCertificateCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFSentinel.obj   ..\source\uCEFServer.obj   ..\source\uCEFServerComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFServerEvents.obj   ..\source\uCEFServerHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFSetCookieCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFSslInfo.obj   ..\source\uCEFStreamReader.obj   ..\source\uCEFStreamWriter.obj   ..\source\uCEFStringList.obj   ..\source\uCEFStringMap.obj   ..\source\uCEFStringMultimap.obj   ..\source\uCEFStringVisitor.obj   ..\source\uCEFTask.obj   ..\source\uCEFTaskRunner.obj   ..\source\uCEFTextfield.obj   ..\source\uCEFTextfieldComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFTextfieldDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFThread.obj   ..\source\uCEFTimerWorkScheduler.obj   ..\source\uCEFTypes.obj   ..\source\uCEFUrlRequest.obj   ..\source\uCEFUrlRequestClientComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFUrlRequestClientEvents.obj   ..\source\uCEFUrlrequestClient.obj   ..\source\uCEFValue.obj   ..\source\uCEFView.obj   ..\source\uCEFViewComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFViewDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFViewsFrameworkEvents.obj   ..\source\uCEFWaitableEvent.obj   ..\source\uCEFWebPluginInfo.obj   ..\source\uCEFWebPluginInfoVisitor.obj   ..\source\uCEFWebPluginUnstableCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFWinControl.obj   ..\source\uCEFWindow.obj   ..\source\uCEFWindowComponent.obj   ..\source\uCEFWindowDelegate.obj   ..\source\uCEFWindowParent.obj   ..\source\uCEFWorkScheduler.obj   ..\source\uCEFWorkSchedulerQueueThread.obj   ..\source\uCEFWorkSchedulerThread.obj   ..\source\uCEFWriteHandler.obj   ..\source\uCEFX509CertPrincipal.obj   ..\source\uCEFX509Certificate.obj   ..\source\uCEFXmlReader.obj   ..\source\uCEFZipReader.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8Accessor.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8ArrayBufferReleaseCallback.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8Context.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8Exception.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8Handler.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8Interceptor.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8StackFrame.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8StackTrace.obj   ..\source\uCEFv8Value.obj   ..\packages\CEF4Delphi_Register.obj   maxicef.obj, +
 maxicef.bpl,, +
  Rxctl5.lib import32.lib cp32mti.lib, +
 , +
 maxicef.res ..\packages\res\chromium.dcr
```

As you can see, `c:\windows\system32;` is included in the paths.

So, I assumed that there is a problem to import 64bit DLLs from a 32bit application, and the whole Internet says it is true.

I started to reimplement those functions in a separate C++ module with code from `Wine`, but it is really very much code. And suddenly I saw that another 32bit DLL of ours built with C++Builder 5 actually DOES reference 64bit DLLs!

[image]

So, what is the trick for calling functions from `System32` 64bit DLLs from a library built with C++Builder 5?

**UPDATE**:

Here is evidence that the functions are actually imported from a parent DLL:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

More one evidence:

[image]

**UPDATE**

OK, here is the makefile:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!if !$d(BCB)
BCB = $(MAKEDIR)\..
!endif

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IDE SECTION
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The following section of the project makefile is managed by the BCB IDE.
# It is recommended to use the IDE to change any of the values in this
# section.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

VERSION = BCB.05.03
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROJECT = maxicef.bpl
OBJFILES = \
#  ..\winlib\winlib.obj \
  ..\addons\MaxiSysUtils.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFAccessibilityHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFApp.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFApplication.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFApplicationCore.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFAudioHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFAuthCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBaseRefCounted.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBaseScopedWrapper.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBeforeDownloadCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBinaryValue.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBitmapBitBuffer.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBoxLayout.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBrowser.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBrowserProcessHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBrowserView.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBrowserViewComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBrowserViewDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFBufferPanel.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFButton.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFButtonComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFButtonDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFChromium.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFChromiumCore.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFChromiumEvents.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFChromiumFontOptions.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFChromiumOptions.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFChromiumWindow.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFClient.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFCommandLine.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFCompletionCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFConstants.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFContextMenuHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFContextMenuParams.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFCookieAccessFilter.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFCookieManager.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFCookieVisitor.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFCustomStreamReader.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDeleteCookiesCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDevToolsMessageObserver.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDialogHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDictionaryValue.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDisplay.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDisplayHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDomDocument.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDomNode.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDomVisitor.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDownLoadItem.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDownloadHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDownloadImageCallBack.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDownloadItemCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDragAndDropMgr.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDragData.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFDragHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFEndTracingCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFExtension.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFExtensionHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFFileDialogCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFFillLayout.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFFindHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFFocusHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFFrame.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFFrameHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFGetExtensionResourceCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFImage.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFInterfaces.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFJsDialogCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFJsDialogHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFJson.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFKeyboardHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLabelButton.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLabelButtonComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLayout.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLibFunctions.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLifeSpanHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLinkedWinControlBase.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLinkedWindowParent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFListValue.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFLoadHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMediaObserver.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMediaRoute.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMediaRouteCreateCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMediaRouter.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMediaSink.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMediaSinkDeviceInfoCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMediaSource.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMenuButton.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMenuButtonComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMenuButtonDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMenuButtonPressedLock.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMenuModel.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMenuModelDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFMiscFunctions.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFNavigationEntry.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFNavigationEntryVisitor.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFOAuth2Helper.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFOLEDragAndDrop.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFOSRIMEHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFOverlayController.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPDFPrintCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPDFPrintOptions.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPanel.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPanelComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPanelDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPostData.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPostDataElement.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPrintDialogCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPrintHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPrintJobCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFPrintSettings.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFProcessMessage.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRegistration.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRenderHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRenderProcessHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRequest.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRequestContext.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRequestContextHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRequestHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResolveCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResourceBundle.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResourceBundleHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResourceHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResourceReadCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResourceRequestHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResourceSkipCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResponse.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFResponseFilter.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRunContextMenuCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFRunFileDialogCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFSSLStatus.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFSchemeHandlerFactory.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFSchemeRegistrar.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFScrollView.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFScrollViewComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFSelectClientCertificateCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFSentinel.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFServer.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFServerComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFServerEvents.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFServerHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFSetCookieCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFSslInfo.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFStreamReader.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFStreamWriter.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFStringList.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFStringMap.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFStringMultimap.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFStringVisitor.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFTask.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFTaskRunner.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFTextfield.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFTextfieldComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFTextfieldDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFThread.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFTimerWorkScheduler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFTypes.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFUrlRequest.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFUrlRequestClientComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFUrlRequestClientEvents.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFUrlrequestClient.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFValue.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFView.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFViewComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFViewDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFViewsFrameworkEvents.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWaitableEvent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWebPluginInfo.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWebPluginInfoVisitor.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWebPluginUnstableCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWinControl.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWindow.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWindowComponent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWindowDelegate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWindowParent.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWorkScheduler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWorkSchedulerQueueThread.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWorkSchedulerThread.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFWriteHandler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFX509CertPrincipal.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFX509Certificate.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFXmlReader.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFZipReader.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8Accessor.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8ArrayBufferReleaseCallback.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8Context.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8Exception.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8Handler.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8Interceptor.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8StackFrame.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8StackTrace.obj \
  ..\source\uCEFv8Value.obj \
  ..\packages\CEF4Delphi_Register.obj \
  maxicef.obj
RESFILES = maxicef.res ..\packages\res\chromium.dcr
MAINSOURCE = maxicef.cpp
RESDEPEN = $(RESFILES)
LIBFILES = 
IDLFILES = 
IDLGENFILES = 
LIBRARIES = Rxctl5.lib
PACKAGES = vcl50.bpi
SPARELIBS = Vcl50.lib Rxctl5.lib
DEFFILE = 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PATHCPP = .;..\winlib;
PATHASM = .;
PATHPAS = .;..\source;..\packages;..\addons;
PATHRC = .;..\packages\res;
DEBUGLIBPATH = $(BCB)\lib\debug;
RELEASELIBPATH = $(BCB)\lib\release
USERDEFINES = _DEBUG;MSWINDOWS;CPUX32;TARGET_32BITS;VER130;
SYSDEFINES = _RTLDLL;NO_STRICT;USEPACKAGES
INCLUDEPATH = ..\source;..\packages;..\addons;..\winlib;$(BCB)\include;$(BCB)\include\vcl
LIBPATH = ..\source;..\packages;..\packages\res;..\addons;..\winlib;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows\SysWOW64;L:\Lib;$(BCB)\lib\obj;$(BCB)\lib;
WARNINGS= -w-par
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CFLAG1 = -Od -Vx -Ve -X- -r- -a8 -b- -k -y -v -vi- -c -tWM -H=vcl50.csm
IDLCFLAGS = -I..\source -I..\packages -I..\addons -I..\winlib -I$(BCB)\include -I$(BCB)\include\vcl \
    -src_suffix cpp -D_DEBUG -DMSWINDOWS -DCPUX32 -DTARGET_32BITS -DVER130 -boa
PFLAGS = -$YD -$W -$O- -v -JPHNE -M
RFLAGS = 
AFLAGS = /mx /w2 /zd
LFLAGS = -D"" -aa -Tpp -x -Gn -Gl -Gi -v
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALLOBJ = c0pkg32.obj $(PACKAGES) Memmgr.Lib sysinit.obj $(OBJFILES)
ALLRES = $(RESFILES)
ALLLIB = $(LIBFILES) $(LIBRARIES) import32.lib cp32mti.lib
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!ifdef IDEOPTIONS

[Version Info]
IncludeVerInfo=0
AutoIncBuild=0
MajorVer=1
MinorVer=0
Release=0
Build=0
Debug=0
PreRelease=0
Special=0
Private=0
DLL=0

[Version Info Keys]
CompanyName=
FileDescription=
FileVersion=1.0.0.0
InternalName=
LegalCopyright=
LegalTrademarks=
OriginalFilename=
ProductName=
ProductVersion=1.0.0.0
Comments=

[Debugging]
DebugSourceDirs=$(BCB)\source\vcl

!endif





# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAKE SECTION
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This section of the project file is not used by the BCB IDE.  It is for
# the benefit of building from the command-line using the MAKE utility.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

.autodepend
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!if "$(USERDEFINES)" != ""
AUSERDEFINES = -d$(USERDEFINES:;= -d)
!else
AUSERDEFINES =
!endif

!if !$d(BCC32)
BCC32 = bcc32ide
!endif

!if !$d(CPP32)
CPP32 = cpp32
!endif

!if !$d(DCC32)
DCC32 = dcc32
!endif

!if !$d(TASM32)
TASM32 = tasm32
!endif

!if !$d(LINKER)
LINKER = ilink32
!endif

!if !$d(BRCC32)
BRCC32 = brcc32
!endif


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!if $d(PATHCPP)
.PATH.CPP = $(PATHCPP)
.PATH.C   = $(PATHCPP)
!endif

!if $d(PATHPAS)
.PATH.PAS = $(PATHPAS)
!endif

!if $d(PATHASM)
.PATH.ASM = $(PATHASM)
!endif

!if $d(PATHRC)
.PATH.RC  = $(PATHRC)
!endif
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(PROJECT): $(IDLGENFILES) $(OBJFILES) $(RESDEPEN) $(DEFFILE)
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(LINKER) @&&!
    $(LFLAGS) -L$(LIBPATH) +
    $(ALLOBJ), +
    $(PROJECT),, +
    $(ALLLIB), +
    $(DEFFILE), +
    $(ALLRES)
!
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.pas.hpp:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(DCC32) $(PFLAGS) -U$(INCLUDEPATH) -D$(USERDEFINES);$(SYSDEFINES) -O$(INCLUDEPATH) --BCB {$< }

.pas.obj:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(DCC32) $(PFLAGS) -U$(INCLUDEPATH) -D$(USERDEFINES);$(SYSDEFINES) -O$(INCLUDEPATH) --BCB {$< }

.cpp.obj:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(BCC32) $(CFLAG1) $(WARNINGS) -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -D$(USERDEFINES);$(SYSDEFINES) -n$(@D) {$< }

.c.obj:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(BCC32) $(CFLAG1) $(WARNINGS) -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -D$(USERDEFINES);$(SYSDEFINES) -n$(@D) {$< }

.c.i:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(CPP32) $(CFLAG1) $(WARNINGS) -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -D$(USERDEFINES);$(SYSDEFINES) -n. {$< }

.cpp.i:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(CPP32) $(CFLAG1) $(WARNINGS) -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -D$(USERDEFINES);$(SYSDEFINES) -n. {$< }

.asm.obj:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(TASM32) $(AFLAGS) -i$(INCLUDEPATH:;= -i) $(AUSERDEFINES) -d$(SYSDEFINES:;= -d) $<, $@

.rc.res:
    $(BCB)\BIN\$(BRCC32) $(RFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -D$(USERDEFINES);$(SYSDEFINES) -fo$@ $<
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE**

For @PaulMcKenzie: I have a 64bit OS, and I need to build a 32bit application with Borland C++Builder 5 to run on the 64bit OS. The problem I have is the issue with the `Unresolved external` errors, when I reference Windows functions residing in Windows DLLs from my `.pas` files.

Comment: 32 dll nothing import or reference from 64 bit dlls

Comment: But see the picture

Comment: and so what ? 32 dll nothing import or reference from 64 bit dlls

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Your 32-bit DLLs do not reference 64-bit DLLs. You cannot load a 32-bit module into a 64-bit process or a 64-bit module into a 32-bit process.

Comment: So Dependecy Walker lying?

Comment: PathIsRelativeA, AlphaBlend, IsWow64Process are still there in 64 bits. There must be a problem somewhere in how you build things

Comment: in list of import modules of your dll - no path. only name. *advapi32.dll* for instance

Comment: *So Dependecy Walker lying?* - yes

Comment: Dependency Walker is not a reliable tool anymore. Though I don't understand what the screenshots are meant to prove either.

Comment: I tried to put full path to DLLs, it doesn't works. So may be Borland system dlls were compiled with 32 bit dlls from windows\system32 and now it redirect user calls with Wow64?

Comment: This project is supposed to provide a replacement: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: That's not how linking works. The linker doesn't care about the DLLs. It uses import libraries (usually with a .LIB extension) to resolve imports.

Comment: I guess linker check that dll actually exists, thus there 'external' keyword used, and it is not handled by compiler.

Comment: No, the linker doesn't check that. It cannot, since it doesn't know where to look for modules. That information is only available after a process has been created, and the OS loader resolves load-time imports.

Comment: So why I get error? I using 'external' keyword, so it must be OK with Borland building system, not? I say that function in external DLL...

Comment: You get the error because you aren't passing the import libraries to the linker.

Comment: The "import libraries" you speak about are dynamic (.dll) or static (.lib)? If dynamic, so how can I pass it? if static, how can I reference function from dynamic?

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova *Access 64 bit DLL from 32 bit DLL* -- Let's take a few steps back.  First, and as mentioned, do you realize that a 64-bit DLL **cannot** access a 32-bit DLL, and vice-versa?  So what are you trying to build?  You are building an application that cannot run correctly, or will abort as soon as that 64-bit DLL is loaded into your 32-bit program (or 32-bit DLL into your 64-bit program).  Regardless of what DependencyWalker is saying, the attempt of building this is going to be an app that doesn't work.

Comment: .LIB files aren't restricted to static libraries. Import libraries for DLLs use the .LIB extension just as well. You would need to pass kernel32.lib to the linker to link against kernel32.dll.

Comment: I get "Fatal: Unable to open file 'KERNEL32.LIB'"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want make 32 bit application that will run on 64 bit windows. I want make in on Delfi with Borland C++ builder. And we already have such applications. I guess it uses Wow64, I just not succeed to reference some windows functions.

Comment: @IInspectable I added makefile, can you say what is wrong there? Where I need to reference kernel32.lib

Comment: A 32 bit application does run on 64 bit windows but it does not directly use any 64 bit dlls

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova -- A 32-bit application running on 64-bit Windows still  must access 32-bit DLL's.  It is not accessing any 64-bit DLL's.  The bottom line is that -- **all** of your modules must be 32-bit for a 32-bit app.  Just because you are running on a 64-bit OS doesn't mean the application is 64-bit.   In the main post, you highlighted the operating system as 64-bit, but that makes no difference.  Is your *application* 64-bit or 32-bit?  It is very confusing as to what the bitness of your *application* is, as to me, you haven't clearly stated what it is.

Comment: OK, so what fix I need do in the code and/or makefile?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, see the update please.

Comment: That's why there are two versions of _Dependency Walker_ available: the [64-bit](https://www.dependencywalker.com/depends22_x64.zip) and the [32-bit](https://www.dependencywalker.com/depends22_x86.zip). When inspecting a 32-bit module, please use the 32-bit Dependency Walker, so it will not assume all the dependent modules to be 64-bit by default. What you see in the screenshots is that 64-bit Dependency Walker is simply assuming the linked Windows DLLs to be 64-bit, and failing (note how those 64-bit icons are painted in red, which means there's a problem).

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova If you were referencing the Win32 functions in **C++** code that passes through the C++ linker, then you would need to include relevant import `.lib`s (`Kernel32.lib`, `Shlwapi.lib`, etc) in your build. Those `.lib`s are provided in BCB's installation. However, some of the functions you are using didn't exist yet (or were introduced shortly before) when BCB5 was released, so they may not exist in the provided `.lib`s, thus you would need to generate updated `.lib`s from the latest `.DLL`s using BCB's `IMPLIB` tool...

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova ... That said, NONE of this applies to **Pascal** code. An `external` declaration referencing a `.DLL` will generate the proper linkage at compile-time to load that `.DLL` at runtime, no import `.lib`s are used. Either way, whether you link via C++ or Pascal, if your app is 32bit, at runtime it will load 32bit DLLs only, using the [system search path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) to find them. Thus, 32bit system DLLs on a 64bit OS will be loaded from the `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64` folder, not the `%WINDIR%\System32` folder.

Comment: To access 32bit dll from 64 bit code and vice versa you need a bridge process (never done this however) here first link I found on google just now https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1199539/Using-64-bit-DLLs-in-32-bit-Processes-with-Out-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, thank you all, for making me understand the process of DLL importing.

As `IInspectable` and `Remy Lebeau` said - the import of `DLL` requires linking with the `LIB`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-lib-files-as-linker-input?view=msvc-160) is more explanations. Also google - "linking a shared library to executable". It is not important whether it is `.so` or `.dll`, the principals are the same.

One other important point before I give a solution.

As `Remy Lebeau` said: several functions

> didn't exist yet (or were introduced shortly before) when BCB5 was released

### Solution

#### First

Fix for makefile

```
LIBRARIES = Rxctl5.lib shlwapi.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib
LIBPATH = ...;..\libs;
```

1. Add all necessary `.lib` files in `LIBRARIES` section.
2. Add a new folder to paths in `LIBPATH` section.

#### Second

Despite presence of folder with `.lib` functions in your `BCB` installation:

[image]

You need to recreate the `.lib` files. I have `Borland C++ builder` installed on `T:\` virtual drive:

```
> cd ..\libs
> T:\Bin\implib.exe kernel32.lib c:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
```

I put the libs in folder `..\libs` relative to the `makefile`.

#### Third

There is a bug in compiler of `Borland`. It fails to compile call to an external function from class method, so you need to add proxies:

```
unit uCEFMiscFunctions;

interface

const
  Kernel32DLL = 'kernel32.dll';

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
function GetGlobalMemoryStatusEx_(lpBuffer: LPMEMORYSTATUSEX): BOOL;
function GetGlobalMemoryStatusEx(lpBuffer: LPMEMORYSTATUSEX): BOOL; stdcall; external Kernel32DLL name 'GlobalMemoryStatusEx';
{$ENDIF}

implementation

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
function GetGlobalMemoryStatusEx_(lpBuffer: LPMEMORYSTATUSEX): BOOL;
begin
  Result := GetGlobalMemoryStatusEx(lpBuffer);
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

```
unit uCEFApplicationCore;
...
function TCefApplicationCore.GetTotalSystemMemory : UInt64;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
var
  TempMemStatus : TMyMemoryStatusEx;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  Result := 0;
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  ZeroMemory(@TempMemStatus, SizeOf(TMyMemoryStatusEx));
  TempMemStatus.dwLength := SizeOf(TMyMemoryStatusEx);
  if GetGlobalMemoryStatusEx_(@TempMemStatus) then
  if True then
    Result := TempMemStatus.ullTotalPhys;
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Third part of the solution did it for me in C++Builder 10.2